# Nginx - WordPress on a domain and a Node.js app in a subdirectory

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, nginx, https

**Issue:** I have an existing WordPress website at https://example.com/. I have a Node.js app that runs on localhost:9001, and I want to have it accessible at https://example.com/subdirectory.

**Request:** Please help me figure out what I need to put in my Nginx server block and/or app.js file in order to get this to work.

For brevity I haven't included all of the things I have attempted, but I can say that I have tried many things over the past couple of days with no success. Any help with this is extremely appreciated!

Here are my relevant files and information:

**Node.js app directory structure**

```
pwd = /home/user/application/

.
├── app.js
├── favicon.ico
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── routes
│   └── routes.js
├── static
│   ├── images
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
└── views
    └── index.html
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');

app.set('ipaddr', '127.0.0.1');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9001);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.use('styles', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'static/styles')));
app.use('scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'static/scripts')));
app.use('images', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'static/images')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.listen(app.set('port'));

module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    root         /var/www/example.com;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_protocols    TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com_cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
location /subdirectory/  {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
 }
```

Will proxy a request for `/subdirectory/foo.html`  to `127.0.0.1:9001/foo.html`

[The nginx proxy-pass documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) has details on behavior with trailing slashes and URI substitution.

Comment: Oh, my goodness... I have no idea why just this one line works, but **THANK YOU!** 

I have tried many different location blocks with various prefixed symbols, and many different types of proxy_* directives in them, but somehow this simple one you provided is the only one that worked.